# Trouble downloading images using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in python scrapy to download some images from a website. When i run my script, I can see the link of images (all of them are in `.jpg` format) in the console. However, when I open the folder in which the images are supposed to be saved when the downloading is done, I get nothing in there. Where I'm making mistakes?

This is my spider (I'm running from sublime text editor):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class YifyTorrentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yifytorrent"

    start_urls= ['https://www.yify-torrent.org/search/1080p/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for q in response.css("article.img-item .poster-thumb"):
            image = response.urljoin(q.css("::attr(src)").extract_first())
            yield {'':image}

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
})
c.crawl(YifyTorrentSpider)
c.start()
```

This is what I've defined in `settings.py` for the images to be saved:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = "/Desktop/torrentspider/torrentspider/spiders/Images"
```

---

To make things clearer:

1. The folder in which I'm expecting the images to be saved named as `Images` which I've placed in the `spider` folder under the project `torrentspider`.
2. Actual address to the `Images` folder is `C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\torrentspider\torrentspider\spiders`.

It's not about running the script successfully with the help of `items.py` file. So, any solution to make the download happen with the use of `items.py` file is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you are yielding does not follow the documentation of Scrapy. As detailed in their [media pipeline documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline) the item should have a field called `image_urls`. You should change your parse method to something similar to this.

```
def parse(self, response):
    images = []
    for q in response.css("article.img-item .poster-thumb"):
        image = response.urljoin(q.css("::attr(src)").extract_first())
        images.append(image)
    yield {'image_urls': images}
```

I just tested this and it works. Additionally, as commented by Pruthvi Kumar, the IMAGES_STORE should just be like

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'Images'
```

Answer (score 0):

What strikes me first thing scanning the code above is the PATH for `IMAGES_STORE`. the `/` means that you are going to the absolute root path of your machine, so you either put the absolute path to where you want to save or just do a relative path from where you are running your crawler

I'm on a linux machine so my absolute path will be something like `IMAGES_STORE = /home/pk/myProjects/scraper/images`

OR

`IMAGES_STORE = 'images'`

Also, most importantly, if you are using default pipeline, the variable which holds the extracted image, (where you do `extract_first()`) must literally be `image_urls`.

You are also missing a couple of steps. In your spider, add this:

```
class ImgData(Item):
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    images=scrapy.Field()
```

In the `yield` step, modify to:

`yield ImgData(image_urls=response.urljoin(q.css("::attr(src)").extract_first()))`

Comment: I already replied how to accomplish this without a items.py file